# How to paginate PrimeNG DataView dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I want to go to some specific page when I have selected the Item in that field. I have tried the following way

```
import {DataViewModule, DataView} from 'primeng/dataview';

// ...

@ViewChild('dataview') dataTable: DataView;

// ...

if (this.selectIndustry) {
            const indxOfIndustry = industries.indexOf(this.selectedIndustry);
            const pageNo = (indxOfIndustry / 10) + 1;
            const paging = {
                first: ((pageNo - 1) * 10),
                rows: 10
            };
            this.dataTable.paginate(paging);
        }
```

But I am getting error message like undefined dataView

Comment: the code snippet which you posted is not adequate to pin-point the issue. Could you post your component's .ts and .html code?

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is access the selector of the **dataView** as **'any'**

**in your HTML file**

```
<p-dataView #dataviewHtml>
...
</p-dataView>
```

**in your TS file**

```
// ...

export class AnyComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('dataviewHtml') dataView: any;

// ...
```

then you can adjust your dataView Paginator anywhere in your TS but not in your ngOnInit, you can use it anywhere afterViewInit

**I used it to go back to the first page of paginator dynamically**

```
this.dataView.first = 0;
```

you can console log the whole Data View Element to see what you're working with

```
console.log('DATA VIEW ', this.dataView);
```

[image]